# How to find $40! \mod 5^{10}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve this congruence. I found that in $40!$ there are $9$ powers of $5$, but I'll need one more for $40!=0 \mod 5^{10}$. I thought about Euler's theorem or Wilson's, but couldn't find any correlation.

Comment: Actually, there are $9$ (because $25=5^2$)...

Answer (score 2):

Because $5^9$ divides $40!$, we can use $ka \bmod kb =k(a \bmod b)\,$ [[mod distributive law]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to get $40! \bmod 5^{10} = 5^9\cdot(\frac{40!}{5^9} \bmod 5)$.  Hence we really only need to find the residue of $\frac {40!}{5^9} \bmod 5$. So separate $n \in 1 \cdots 40$ into two sets, those divisible by $5$ and those coprime to $5$:

The product of the $n$ coprime to $5$ is
$$  (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4)^8 \equiv 1 \pmod 5,$$
whereas the multiples of $5$ (with all the fives divided out) contribute
$$ 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \equiv (-1) \pmod 5.$$
Hence, we can write $$5^9 (\frac {40!}{5^9} \bmod 5) = 5^9 (1 \cdot -1 \bmod 5) = 5^9 \cdot 4$$

Comment: I don't think you can compute the mod 5 residual that way

Comment: I added explanation. Note that 5^9 (1+5k) = 5^9 + k 5^10.

Comment: I don't quite understand why 40!/5^9≡(1⋅2⋅3⋅4)^8  mod 5

Comment: The result is actually $4\cdot 5^9$.

Comment: For the first part he is using the fact that $( (ka) \bmod (kb)) = k(a \bmod b)$

Comment: @Mathapprentice He's being unclear (not sure why).  He's separating $n \in 1 \cdots 40$ into two groups, those that are divisible by 5 and those that aren't.  For  those that aren't, they are of the form $n=5a + b$ where $b$ goes $1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 \dots$

Comment: @DanielV yes, I figured it out in the meantime. Now I'm putting the pieces all together

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear about the steps, I wrote the solution in bit of a rush. Feel free to edit it if anyone feels like it need refinement and/or clarification! :)

Comment: it's alright. Thanks for the explanation. Turns out it's a bit more challenging than I thought

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch Took up your offer to edit, please check if it matches your intentions closely enough

Comment: How did you get 1⋅2⋅3⋅4⋅1⋅1⋅2⋅3≡(−1)(mod5).